# Pathlib with_name does not rename file

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

File is not renamed by `with_name()`. A test file is created at Path p using `touch()` and updated using `with_name()`.
1.) Is there an issue caused by usage of Path vs PurePath? (no)
2.) Is it necessary to call `replace()` using the updated path object to change the file name on disk? (yes)

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('./test.txt')

p.touch()

print(f'p before: {p}')
# ==> p before: test.txt

# p is not updated
p.with_name('test_new.txt')
print(f'p after:  {p}')
# ==> p after: test.txt
```

Comment: This code works on Windows 10 for me -- can you provide the exact console output (including errors) that you are getting?

Comment: From the docs: "PurePath.with_name(name) Return *a new path* with the name changed. [...]". You have to *assign* the result of ``p.with_name()``, or it is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the path using `with_name()` is insufficient to rename the corresponding file on the filesystem. I was able to rename the file by explicitly calling `.replace()` with the updated path object (see below).

`p.replace(p.with_name('test_new.txt'))`

Per MisterMiyagi's comment above:

> From the docs: "PurePath.with_name(name) Return a new path with the
>   name changed. [...]". You have to assign the result of p.with_name(),
>   or it is lost.

```
### WORKS ###
from pathlib import Path

# sets original path
p = Path('./test.txt')
print(p)
# ==> test.txt

# create file on disk
p.touch()

# prints updated path, but does not update p (due to immutability?)
print(p.with_name('test_new.txt')) 
# ==> test_new.txt

# p not updated
print(p)
# ==> test.txt

# assignment to q stores updated path
q = p.with_name('test_new.txt')
print(q)
# ==> test_new.txt

# file on disk is updated with new file name
p.replace(p.with_name('test_new.txt'))
# p.replace(q) # also works
print(p)
# ==> test_new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`path.with_name()` will generate a new Path object.
`path.rename()` will generate a new Path object and call the new path object's  touch method.

So the `path.rename()` will be the proper way.